# Maven + Scala + Java + Pelops = trouble

Tags: java, scala, maven, pelops

I've a project in Java and Scala and I use maven to compile it.
A Java class uses Pelops to access a Cassandra database and it is all fine (maven compile the entire project), but when I try to access Cassandra from a Scala object (using tha same import as in the Java fil) maven give me this error :

```
[ERROR] error: error while loading Bytes, Missing dependency 'class com.eaio.uuid.UUID', required by /home/dacanalr/.m2/repository/pelops/pelops/1.0/pelops-1.0.jar(org/scale7/cassandra/pelops/Bytes.class)
```

What this mean and how can I solve ? I don't understand why from Java file it works, but don't from Scala source...

Comment: I added uuid-3.2.jar to the project and now seems to work

Answer (score 0):

15 seconds in Google to find this page, which I think contains a library you need at runtime

http://johannburkard.de/software/uuid/